# Adding a registry key via batch file

Tags: windows, windows-registry, batch-file

could anyone tell me how exactly to do this via a batch file: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3123303

The x86 version. Much appreciated.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/761008/add-registry-key-entries-using-batch-file, http://superuser.com/questions/991178/how-to-add-reg-key-from-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

Using `regedit`.

First create a file containing the keys you want to merge. There is a StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334207/regedit-file-format) which goes into a little bit more detail about the format of the file. There is also a [official Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516) which documents the format fully.

Then, simply running the following command should merge all the entries in the file passed as an argument

```
regedit fileToMerge.reg
```

---

You can find several explanations/guides on using regedit, such as [this one](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php) (can't vouch for it, just the first link that popped up in Google).